# RDP Session Share and Viewer using StartReverseConnectListener

Tags: c#, rdp

There are 3 steps to accomplish a reverse connection to overcome NAT/Firewalls:

1. On the RDPSession side create an invitation

   ```
   RDPSession session = new RDPSession(); 
   session.Open(); 
   string hostConnString = session.Invitations.CreateInvitation(null, "My Group Name", "12345", 1)
   ```
2. On the RDP viewer side you initiate a reverse connect

   ```
   string viewerConnString = axRDPViewer1.StartReverseConnectListener(hostConnString, "My Name", "12345");
   ```
3. Back on the RDP session side connects to the viewer

   ```
   session.ConnectToClient(viewerConnString);
   ```

Here my question: on Step #2 to initiate start reverse connect, `StartReverseConnectListener()`. Where should I call this method? Is it on `OnConnectionFailed` event after the standard viewer connect has failed or is it just always replacing the standard viewer connect method.

On Step #3. which event on the host `RDP` session should I place this call so that seamlessly connects the `client` (viewer).

Comment: I have found similar question a resposnse was provided but not explanation on the approach for this solution. here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742325/rdpsession-connecttoclient-terminating-unexpectedly