# C# RDP Client - Server reverse connection

Tags: c#, rdp

I don't have an exact problem but would like to brainstorm about the following. I have an RDP server and client, the server generates a string and waits for connections from the client.

Once this is iniated the client see's the server his desktop and can control it. However somebody told me it's possible when this connection is established to reverse the connection.

Here is the code of my server :

```
using RDPCOMAPILib;

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RDP Server starting !");
            createSession();
            Connect(currentSession);
            string connect = getConnectionString(currentSession, "Test", "Group", "", 5);
            Console.WriteLine(connect + "<=== THIS IS YOUR STRING TO CONNECT !");
        i = true;
    }
```

Somebody gave me the following hint for what I want to achieve :

When the attendee(client) is connected to the server,if you play a little with the IRDPSRAPISharingSession *session,you can call it's member function session->ConnectToClient to make a reverse connection.Very simple...

Does this make sense for anyone or anyone has some ideas how to implement ?

Comment: I did not include the code for purpose here because I want to discuss the general idea. To give you some idea of what im doing I included the server part just to give you an idea..

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742325/rdpsession-connecttoclient-terminating-unexpectedly/38701940#38701940 , may help you.